# programming Aces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, blackjack, playing-cards

I am running into a problem calculating whether or not the Ace Value should be 1 or 11.

For example:
Hand({value: 11, suit: 2}, {value: 3, suit: 1}) ; // Ace-3 could be 4 or 14 depending on the next card to come

my current calculation doesn't handle this and I cant seem to come up with a way to implement it.

first I fill an array with card objects

```
function fillDeck(numDecks, deck){
    cardNum = 0;
    for(let i =0;i <= numDecks -1; i++ ){
        for(let s = 1; s<=4; s++){
            for(let v = 2; v <= 14; v++){
                cardType = calcCard(v);
                value = calcValue(v);
                suit = calcSuit(s);
            deck[cardNum] = new Card(value, s, 'img/cards/' + cardType + '_' + 'of_' + suit + '.png');
            cardNum++;
            }
        } 
    }
} 
Deck = [];
fillDeck(5, Deck);
```

Deal Cards:

```
 function dealCards(player, dealer, deck){
    player.push(deck.pop());
    dealer.push(deck.pop());
    player.push(deck.pop());
    dealer.push(deck.pop());

}
```

Then my way to calculate a Hands

```
 function calcHand(Hand){
    var handValue = 0;
    for(let hand of Hand){
        handValue += hand.value;
    }
    return handValue;
}
```

this simply just returns the value of 14.

so on the next hit

```
Hand.push(Deck.pop());
```

I add a new card to the hand

```
Hand({value: 11, suit: 2}, {value: 3, suit: 1}, {value: 2, suit: 1});
```

now the hand is 6/16

But what if the 3rd or 4th card is an ace?  This is where I keep running into an issue with solving this problem.

My current solution is :

```
 while(calcHand(playerHand) <=16 && dealerHand[1].value > 6 | calcHand(playerHand) <12)
    {
            var currentCard = Deck.pop();


            if(currentCard.value === 11 && calcHand(playerHand) < 11){
                currentCard.value = 11;
                console.log("Ace = 11 : Value : " + currentCard.value);

            }else if(currentCard.value === 11 && calcHand(playerHand) >= 11){
                currentCard.value = 1;
                console.log("Ace = 1 : Value : " + currentCard.value);
            }
            if(hasAce && (calcHand(playerHand) + currentCard.value) > 21 && 
               playerHand.map(x => x.value).indexOf(11) > -1){ 
               var acePosition = playerHand.map(x => x.value).indexOf(11);
               playerHand[acePosition].value = 1;

            }
        playerHand.push(currentCard);
        }
```

Comment: Your summing logic needs to know about aces specifically.  Your first pass should count aces as their maximum value (11) and, if that pushes you over the limit, then  knock one down to 1.  If still over the limit, knock the next one down to 1 and so on.  Either that or you calculate all possible sums your hand could have and base your play decision based on the best sum.

Comment: Have you tried defining the ace as an array `[1, 11]`?

Comment: When the player no longer wants a hit, then you need them to choose what they want the Ace value to be.

Answer (score 1):

Handling aces in blackjack is simple once you realize that it's never a choice. The rules are:

1. Aces count one. Period. Now total the hand.
2. IF the total is less than 12, AND the hand contains at least
      one ace, add 10 and mark it "soft".

Done.